# Difference Java Media Framework API and FMJ

Tags: java, jmf, fmj

I want capture the data from scanner, camera, USB camera for all operating systems.

What is difference between Java Media Framework API and FMJ?  Which API is better?

**Update**

Is there any possible to capture the data from scanner using JMF?

Comment: AFAIU, FMJ uses and expands on JMF.

Comment: what is AFAIU?.I am trying to search on AFAIU?.I didn't get the proper url.Please put resource also?

Comment: "As Far As I Understand"

Answer (score 4):

FMJ is an open source replacement for JMF.
It is able to capture live video from a USB camera using the LTI-CIVIL library.
There is no scanner integration AFAIK.
There are some libraries out there for java and scanners, open and closed source.
Have a look at jtwain, jsane, etc:

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/11/18/twain.html
http://asprise.com/product/jsane/index.php